# Windows XP Mode in Windows 7 Professional

Tags: windows-7, start-menu, windows-xp-mode

I have installed an application which is not compatible with Windows 7 within Windows XP Mode and it works well.

How do I get this application into the Windows 7 start menu, so I don't have to load up the Windows XP Mode each time, select Windows XP's start menu, and start the XP application.  From videos I've seen, I should be able to add the application to the Windows 7 start menu and load it straight from there.

Comment: This typically occurs automatically when you run an installer in the Windows XP Mode VM.  Did this application not have an installer (e.g. just a copy)?

Comment: The application does have an installer.  I even selected the Install for all users when I started the installer instead of Install just for me.

Comment: Can you confirm it didn't get put into     KEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Virtual Machine\VPCVAppExcludeList in the XP VM?

Otherwise, there is a SU possible duplicate question here http://superuser.com/questions/84275/creating-an-app-shortcut-in-windows-7-xp-mode

Comment: I'll check the registry key ASAP!  I will hopefully get back to you before the end of the day.  The computer on which this is being done, I switched off, and it applying 122 updates... So it's going to take some time before I can check the regkey.

Comment: Additional, from what I've read it seems that if the program is installed through the XP Mode that it should create those shortcuts automatically.

Comment: @oshirowanen Glad it helped.  I've converted to an official answer, if you could accept it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows XP Mode under Windows 7 should create application automatically during installation save some restriction applications which can be modified in a registry list as described below.

There are two registry keys for the application control:

**Exclude:**

KEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Virtual Machine\VPCVAppExcludeList
and

**Include:**

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Virtual Machine\VPCVAppIncludeList

However, if it's simple something that needs to be manually created that answer is available at [SO Manual Shortcut for XP Mode Application](If the [Creating an app shortcut in Windows 7 XP Mode](https://superuser.com/questions/84275/creating-an-app-shortcut-in-windows-7-xp-mode)) which describes a manual method for creating shortcuts to launch applications in XP Mode on Windows 7.

**Additional Information**

The Windows XP Mode locations and installation/usage instructions can be found at [Install and use Windows XP Mode](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/install-and-use-windows-xp-mode-in-windows-7).